# ¿Cómo animar y modificar el atributo "d" en el <path> de un SVG? (Ejemplo convertir un circulo a cuadrado)

Tags: css, svg, animación, frontend

Quisiera lograr crear una **`animación fluida`** de un SVG que se **transforme de un circulo a un cuadrado** por medio de modificar el atributo "d" de la etiqueta `<path>`.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lo más importante es tener los dos trazados con los mismos comandos** en el mismo orden y número. Por ejemplo a continuación tengo un circulo hecho de 4 curvas cúbicas Bézier, y un cuadrado también creado utilizando 4 curvas cúbicas Bézier:

```html
<svg viewBox="-52 -52 104 104" width="300" fill="none" stroke="red">
  <path d="M-50,0
           C-50 -27.614 -27.614 -50 0 -50
           C27.614 -50 50 -27.614 50 0
           C50 27.614 27.614 50 0 50
           C-27.614 50 -50 27.614 -50 0Z"       
        />
  <path d="M-50.000, 0.000 
           C-33.333, -16.667 -16.667, -33.333 0.000, -50.000 
           C16.667, -33.333 33.333, -16.667 50.000, 0.000 
           C33.333, 16.667 16.667, 33.333 0.000, 50.000 
           C-16.667, 33.333 -33.333, 16.667 -50.000, 0.000 Z"       
        />
  </svg>
```

Ahora puedes animar de circulo a cuadrado utilizando por ejemplo animaciones SMIL:

```html
<svg viewBox="-52 -52 104 104" width="300" fill="none" stroke="red">
  <path d="M-50,0
           C-50 -27.614 -27.614 -50 0 -50
           C27.614 -50 50 -27.614 50 0
           C50 27.614 27.614 50 0 50
           C-27.614 50 -50 27.614 -50 0Z">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M-50,0
           C-50 -27.614 -27.614 -50 0 -50
           C27.614 -50 50 -27.614 50 0
           C50 27.614 27.614 50 0 50
           C-27.614 50 -50 27.614 -50 0Z;
           
           M-50.000, 0.000 
           C-33.333, -16.667 -16.667, -33.333 0.000, -50.000 
           C16.667, -33.333 33.333, -16.667 50.000, 0.000 
           C33.333, 16.667 16.667, 33.333 0.000, 50.000 
           C-16.667, 33.333 -33.333, 16.667 -50.000, 0.000 Z;
                    
           M-50,0
           C-50 -27.614 -27.614 -50 0 -50
           C27.614 -50 50 -27.614 50 0
           C50 27.614 27.614 50 0 50
           C-27.614 50 -50 27.614 -50 0Z" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Por favor observa que el atributo `values` del elemento `<animate>` contiene una lista de valores separados por `;`. El primer valor es el atributo d para el circulo, el segundo valor es el atributo d para el cuadrado, y el tercero es de nuevo el atributo d para el circulo.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que quería lograr, muchas gracias por la ayuda.